# Why did Apache IoTDB report 301 type error when exporting tsfile?

Tags: database, export, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I use "export-tsfile.sh" in Apache IoTDB, an error popped out when exporting tsfile. I tried to execute 230 SQL statements in total. When executing the second line, the error reported: "Cannot dump result because: 301: DriverTask 20230711_074651_64614_1.1.0.0 is aborted by timeout". I did not quite understand this error content, anyone knows how should I solve it?  301 type error when exporting tsfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like timeout for the export tsfile process. You can try to increase the timeout parameter, `-t <timeout>` in the command line of Apache IoTDB and try again.